# Notepad++ keyboard shortcut for "No" not working any more

Tags: notepad++

The quickest way to close a file I don't need, I used to press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
and then <kbd>N</kbd> for No.

Since a while, this is not working any more. The <kbd>N</kbd> is not working, so I have to use the mouse here.

Any idea, why this default keys are not working any more?

Comment: Works here. Try to uninstall Notepad++, scrub all its folders and re-install the latest version.

Comment: BTW, you can use `right arrow` instead of `N` to get the same effect.

Comment: Yes, but since I use this shortcut dozens of times a day I would be happy to have the short version back :-)

Comment: Thanks @harryymc: re-installing did the trick! Probably it was because I had accidentally installed the 32 Bit instead of the 64 Bit version? Anyway, now with the 64 Bit the shortcuts are back. 

And since I had just installed the system some days ago, I did not try to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @harrymc:

Even though I had just installed notepad++ some days ago, **re-installing did the trick**.

I also noticed that I had installed before the 32 Bit version, now the 64 Bit.

Hope this helps others.